# AWS Metric Filter in Cloudwatch split function

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am having below log trail,from which I am interested in getting the alarm setup for duration going above 10000ms,I am not able to split ms

2023-08-28 11:57:58,204 INFO  [server.log.api40] service getTicketDemoList complete: 2000ms =====

Thank you.

Tried below Filter Pattern

[date,timestamp,loglevel,service,msg3=getTicketDemoList,msg4,responsetime=%[0-9]%]

it returning response time value as 2000ms,I want to create alert based on the response time.

And also I want to get this query triggered from lambda.